# Can't intent the result of the matched image on the next activity

Tags: android

CameraActicity:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static String TAG = "OpenCVLibrary";

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCv Not Successfully Loaded");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCv Successfully Loaded");
        }
    }

    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    DBController db;
    ImageProcessing imgproc;
    Button btnProcess;
    Cursor res;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ImageView imgTaken;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Camera");
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        }
        //Initialize View
        imgTaken = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTaken);
        btnProcess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProcess);
        btnProcess.setEnabled(false);
        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        //Create a Bitmap of the Image captured using camera
        //imgTaken.setImageBitmap(getTakenImage());
        //Set OnClick Listener
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnProcess.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public Bitmap getTakenImage(){
        //String path = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()+"/pic.jpg";
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imgTaken.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        return bmp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.btnProcess:
                Cursor res;
                db = new DBController(this);

                process();

                break;

            //pagpicture
            case R.id.btnBack:
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                //finish();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //result nung camera
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                new Utility(CameraActivity.this).SaveTemp(bp,""+1);
                btnProcess.setEnabled(true);
                imgTaken.setImageBitmap(bp);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
    }


    public void process(){
        final String TAG = "Image Processing";
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CameraActivity.this);

        final ArrayList<ProcessResult> processResults = new ArrayList<>();
        db = new DBController(this);
        imgproc = new ImageProcessing();
        AsyncTask<String,String,String> task = new AsyncTask<String, String, String> () {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                //Processing Dialog

                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing Image  \nPlease wait!...");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                /*Compute for the Match Percentage of the Image
                compareFeature Method
                First Params = Plant Image
                Second Params = Image Taken

                Retrieve all Plant Image in the Database
                */
                try {
                    res = db.getAllData("tableplantdetails");
                    Log.d(TAG, "" + res.getCount());

                    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                        //String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.thesis.app.parafish/files/" + res.getString(2);
                        //Bitmap tmpbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
                        int rate = 0;

                        Log.d(TAG,rate+"");
                        do {
                            Log.e(TAG, res.getString(0) + "/" + res.getString(1) + "/" + res.getString(2)+ "/" + res.getString(3)+ "/" + res.getString(4));
                            String imgpath = res.getString(3);
                            String[] newimgpath = imgpath.split("/");
                            String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.example.geraldine.myisucculent/files/" + newimgpath[1];
                            Bitmap tmpbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);

                            ProcessResult result = new ProcessResult();

                            if(tmpbmp!=null &&getTakenImage()!=null){

                                rate = compareFeature(tmpbmp, getTakenImage());

                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, rate + "");
                            result.setplantID(res.getString(0));
                            result.setResult(rate);
                            processResults.add(result);

                        } while (res.moveToNext());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d(TAG,"here");
                Collections.sort(processResults, new ArraySort());
                /*Rearrange the Top 3 Best Match. Result with the same Parasite ID with the highest Match
                remain while the other one will be remove from the list
                By doing this ArrayList with Index from 0-2 is now the Top 3 Match with different parasite id
                */
                for(int i = 0; i < processResults.size(); i++){
                    Log.d("Top3",processResults.get(i).getResult().toString());
                }
                int index = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < processResults.size()-1; i++){
                    ProcessResult result1 = processResults.get(i);
                    for(int y=i+1;y < (processResults.size()-1)-i;y++){
                        ProcessResult result2 = processResults.get(y);
                        Log.d("Top3",result1.getplantID()+" Compared to "+result2.getplantID());
                        if(result1.getplantID().equals(result2.getplantID())){
                            processResults.remove(i+1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < processResults.size(); i++){
                    Log.d("Top3","ID="+processResults.get(i).getplantID()+"  Rate:"+processResults.get(i).getResult().toString());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //tempo
                Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, Match.class);
                //startActivity(intentcam);

                //Nagfoforce close dahil dito...
                intent.putExtra("top1",processResults.get(0).getplantID());
                intent.putExtra("percentage1",processResults.get(0).getResult()+"");
                Log.d("Top1","ID="+processResults.get(0).getplantID()+"  Rate:"+processResults.get(0).getResult().toString());

                intent.putExtra("top2",processResults.get(1).getplantID());
                intent.putExtra("percentage2",processResults.get(1).getResult()+"");
                Log.d("Top2","ID="+processResults.get(1).getplantID()+"  Rate:"+processResults.get(1).getResult().toString());

                intent.putExtra("top3",processResults.get(2).getplantID());
                intent.putExtra("percentage3",processResults.get(2).getResult()+"");
                Log.d("Top3","ID="+processResults.get(2).getplantID()+"  Rate:"+processResults.get(2).getResult().toString());

                intent.putExtra("from","CameraActivity");

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        task.execute("");
    }
 public int compareFeature(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        final String TAG = "FEATURE_MATCH";
        int percentage = 0;
        Log.d(TAG,"Start Comparing");
        // Load images to compare
        bmp1 = bmp1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        bmp2 = bmp2.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Mat img1 = new Mat();
        Mat img2 = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp1, img1);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp2, img2);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        Log.d(TAG,"Bitmap Converted to GrayScale");
        // Declare key point of images
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
        Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
        Log.d(TAG,"Keypoints and Descriptor Initialize");
        // Definition of ORB key point detector and descriptor extractors
        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);
        DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SIFT);

        // Detect key points
        detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
        detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
        Log.d(TAG,"KeyPoints Detected");

        // Extract descriptors
        extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
        extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);
        Log.d("OpenCVLibrary","Extract Descriptors");
        // Definition of descriptor matcher
        DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED);

        // Match points of two images
        //MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
        List<MatOfDMatch> matches = new LinkedList<MatOfDMatch>();
        // Avoid to assertion failed
        // Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)
        if (descriptors1.type() == descriptors2.type() &&
                descriptors1.cols() == descriptors2.cols()) {
            //matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
            matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches,2);
            //List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
            LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();

            float nndrRatio = 0.8f;
            Log.d("OpenCVLibrary","Total No of Match:"+matches.size()+"");

            for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
                MatOfDMatch matofDMatch = matches.get(i);
                DMatch[] dmatcharray = matofDMatch.toArray();
                DMatch m1 = dmatcharray[0];
                DMatch m2 = dmatcharray[1];

                if (m1.distance <= m2.distance * nndrRatio) {
                    good_matches.addLast(m1);

                }
            }
            MatOfDMatch goodEnough = new MatOfDMatch();
            goodEnough.fromList(good_matches);

            Log.d("OpenCVLibrary","Total No of GM:"+good_matches.size()+"");
            double matchCount = matches.size();
            double goodMatch = good_matches.size();
            Log.d("OpenCVLibrary","Computation: ("+goodMatch+"/"+matchCount+")");
            double tmp =(goodMatch/matchCount);
            Log.d("OpenCVLibrary","Computation: "+tmp+"*100");

            double tmp2 =  tmp*100;
            percentage = (int) tmp2;
            Log.d("OpenCVLibrary","Total Percentage:"+percentage+"");



        }
        return percentage;

    }

}
```

MatchActivity

```
public class Match extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView img1,img2,img3;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tnote;
    CardView cv1,cv2,cv3;
    Cursor res;
    DBController db = new DBController(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match);
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Best Match");

        String path = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).toString();

        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtop1);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtop2);
        img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtop3);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percent1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percent2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percent3);
        tnote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNote);

        cv1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.top1);
        cv2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.top2);
        cv3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.top3);


        cv1.setOnClickListener(this);
        cv2.setOnClickListener(this);
        cv3.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getStringExtra("top1")==""){
            cv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tnote.setText("No Succulent Match");

        }
        else if(null != intent){
            Log.e("Top3",intent.getStringExtra("percentage1"));
            Log.e("Top3",intent.getStringExtra("percentage2"));
            Log.e("Top3",intent.getStringExtra("percentage3"));
            Log.e("Top3",intent.getStringExtra("top1"));
            Log.e("Top3",intent.getStringExtra("top2"));
            Log.e("Top3",intent.getStringExtra("top3"));

            String p1 = intent.getStringExtra("percentage1");
            String p2 = intent.getStringExtra("percentage2");
            String p3 = intent.getStringExtra("percentage3");

            tv1.setText(tv1.getText().toString()+p1+"%");
            tv2.setText(tv2.getText().toString()+p2+"%");
            tv3.setText(tv3.getText().toString()+p3+"%");



            res = db.getSpecificData("tableplantdetails","plantID="+intent.getStringExtra("top1"));
            res.moveToFirst();
            String imgpath = res.getString(3);
            String[] newimgpath = imgpath.split("/");
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+"/"+newimgpath[1]);

            if(img!=null){
                img1.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
            res = db.getSpecificData("tableplantdetails","plantID="+intent.getStringExtra("top2"));
            res.moveToFirst();
            String imgpath2 = res.getString(3);
            String[] newimgpath2 = imgpath2.split("/");
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+"/"+newimgpath2[1]);
            if(img!=null){
                img2.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
            res = db.getSpecificData("tableplantdetails","plantID="+intent.getStringExtra("top3"));
            res.moveToFirst();
            String imgpath3 = res.getString(3);
            String[] newimgpath3 = imgpath3.split("/");
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+"/"+newimgpath3[1]);
            if(img!=null){
                img3.setImageBitmap(img);
            }

            if(p1.equals("0")){
                cv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }if(p2.equals("0")){
                cv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }if(p3.equals("0")){
                cv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Intent nIntent;
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.top1:
                nIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),view_succulent_info.class);
                nIntent.putExtra("plantID",intent.getStringExtra("top1"));
                startActivity(nIntent);
                break;
            case  R.id.top2:
                nIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),view_succulent_info.class);
                nIntent.putExtra("plantID",intent.getStringExtra("top2"));
                startActivity(nIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.top3:
                nIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),view_succulent_info.class);
                nIntent.putExtra("plantID",intent.getStringExtra("top3"));
                startActivity(nIntent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

DBController (Database)

```
public class DBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    //Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "isucculents.db";

    //Tables Name
    private static final String TABLE_PLANTS = "tableplantdetails";
    private static final String TABLE_DISEASE = "tableplantdisease";
    private static final String TABLE_HISTORY = "tablehistory";

    //plant details column names
    public static final String KEY_PLANTID = "plantID";
    public static final String KEY_PLANTNAME = "plantname";
    public static final String KEY_PDESCRIPTION = "plantdescription";
    public static final String KEY_PIMAGEPATH = "plantimagepath";
    public static final String KEY_PIMAGETYPE = "plantimagetype";
    public  static final String KEY_PSTATUS = "status";
    public static final String[] ALL_PKEYS = new String[] {KEY_PLANTID, KEY_PLANTNAME, KEY_PDESCRIPTION, KEY_PIMAGEPATH, KEY_PIMAGETYPE, KEY_PSTATUS};

    //Plant Disease Column Names
    public static final String KEY_DISEASEID = "plantdiseaseID";
    public static final String KEY_DISEASENAME = "plantdiseasename";
    public   static final String KEY_DDESCRIPTION = "plantdiseasedescription";
    public  static final String KEY_DIMAGEPATH = "plantdiseaseimagepath";
    public  static final String KEY_DSTATUS = "status";
    public static final String KEY_DPLANTID = "plantID";
    public static final String[] ALL_DKEYS = new String[] {KEY_DISEASEID, KEY_DISEASENAME, KEY_DDESCRIPTION, KEY_DIMAGEPATH, KEY_DSTATUS, KEY_DPLANTID};

    //History Column Names 2
    public static final String KEY_HISID = "historyID";
    public static final String KEY_HISCUREID = "recommendedcureID";
    public static final String KEY_HISPLANTNAME = "plantname";
    public static final String KEY_HISCAPTUREDIMAGE = "capturedimagefilepath";
    public static final String KEY_HISDATEDETECTED = "datedetected";
    public static final String KEY_HISSTATUS = "status";
    public static final String [] ALL_HISKEYS = new String[] {KEY_HISID,KEY_HISCUREID,KEY_HISPLANTNAME,KEY_HISCAPTUREDIMAGE,KEY_HISDATEDETECTED,KEY_HISSTATUS};

    private Context mContext;
    private static String TAG = "DBController";

    public DBController (Context context) {

        super(context, "/mnt/sdcard/"+DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_PLANTS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableplantdetails(" +
                "plantID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +
                "plantname TEXT," +
                "plantdescription TEXT," +
                "plantimagepath TEXT," +
                "plantimagetype TEXT," +
                "status TEXT)";
        String CREATE_DISEASE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableplantdisease(" +
                "plantdiseaseID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +
                "plantdiseasename TEXT," +
                "plantdiseasedescription TEXT," +
                "plantdiseaseimagepath TEXT," +
                "status TEXT," +
                "plantID INTEGER)";
        String CREATE_HISTORY = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablehistory(" +
                "historyID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                "recordID INTEGER," +
                "detecteddiseaseID INTEGER," +
                "recommendedcureID INTEGER," +
                "plantname TEXT," +
                "capturedimagefilepath TEXT," +
                "datedetected TEXT," +
                "status TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_PLANTS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DISEASE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_HISTORY);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int il, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLANTS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DISEASE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_HISTORY);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData(String tbl_Name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM %s",tbl_Name),null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getSpecificData(String tbl_Name, String WhereClause){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql= String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s",tbl_Name,WhereClause );
        Log.d("SQL Query",sql);
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        return res;
    }


    public boolean saveforMonitoring(HashMap<String,String> queryValues){
        SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        Utility util = new Utility(mContext);
        long result = -1;
        final downloadImage downImage = new downloadImage();

        Log.d(TAG,"Saving Data for Monitoring");
        values.put("historyID", queryValues.get("id"));
        values.put("recordID", queryValues.get("recordid"));
        values.put("detecteddiseaseID", queryValues.get("dis_id"));
        values.put("recommendedcureID", queryValues.get("cure_id"));
        values.put("plantname", queryValues.get("plantname"));
        values.put("capturedimagepathfile", "IMG_"+queryValues.get("image")+".jpg");
        values.put("datedetected", queryValues.get("date"));
        String root = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()+"/temp/IMG_temp.jpg";
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root);
        util.SaveImage(bmp,queryValues.get("image"));
        result = db.insert("tablehistory", null, values);
        db.close();

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

LOGCAT

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.geraldine.myisucculent, PID: 6262
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
>           at com.example.geraldine.myisucculent.CameraActivity$1.onPostExecute(CameraActivity.java:236)
>           at com.example.geraldine.myisucculent.CameraActivity$1.onPostExecute(CameraActivity.java:144)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>   Application terminated.

[this is my logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlS73.png)

Comment: which line is line 236?

Comment: In camera activity

Comment: intent.putExtra("top1",processResults.get(0).getplantID());

Comment: Your error tell us that there is nothing at index 0. This means the code isn't reaching `processResults.add(result);` At `if (res.moveToFirst())` Create a breakpoint and this code block and see what it returns. If it does return true, step into the do block and confirm and see what `result.setplantID(res.getString(0));` returns, I suspect nothing.Let me know.

Comment: how will i do that?

Comment: Have a look at a guide like [this](https://www.strv.com/blog/debugging-in-android-studio-as) that is the first one I found on google there are plenty of others. Knowing how to debug and read logcat errors will go a long way in improving your knowledge of programming. This is fundamental stuff.

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) official one from google is more complete